# How to get the truncating index in UILabel in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel

How to get the truncating index in UILabel without ellipsis (...).

I Have a big text content and I want to break it according to screen size and show to the next horizontal page using CollectionView.
And without ellipsis because am using attributed text. It is not showing ellipsis.

If it is not possible please tell me another way to break the text content in horizontal page.

Comment: Are you asking for `myLabel.lineBreakMode = .byClipping` ?

Comment: No, I need index number of the character that clipping.

Comment: This article is a few years old, so some code specifics may be out-of-date, but it is probably a great starting point for your task: https://www.kodeco.com/578-core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app